# Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()' in Fragment class

Tags: java, android

```
private void showToast(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Should I change to `getActivity()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` must be called on an instance of a `Context` class, so yes, you should call:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

You can also just pass `getActivity` as the first parameter since the activity itself extends `Context` class.